# i can't insert data in my existing table with SELECT INTO of MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have another idea that can be more performante than the solution given in my last include question : [solution of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444533/issue-with-execution-query-of-update-table-in-stored-trigger/34444848#34444848)
And this is my suggestion but it doesn't work!

```
SELECT 
    32,
    57,     
    'MVT/15/12/0001',
    'BSR/15/12/001',
    'S',
    'ART_039',
    'AAAA',
    a.qte_art,
    1,
    a.qte_art - 1,
    'uuuu'
INTO mvt(id_piece, article_id_article, code_mvt, origine_mvt, type_mvt, code_art, des_art, qte_old, qte_mvt, qte_new, link_piece)
FROM article a
WHERE a.id_article = 57

#1327 - Undeclared variable: mvt
```

Please chek my question in the link because the resean i tried this solution is that i have a trigger on mvt table

Comment: Does mvt table exist? Also why not `insert into` as opposed to `select into`?

Comment: Please chek my question in the link because the resean i tried this solution is that i have a trigger

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use 
`insert into table(fields) select fields from xxx`

Comment: Please chek my question in the link because the resean i tried this solution is that i have a trigger

Comment: MySQL Server doesn't support the SELECT ... INTO TABLE Sybase SQL extension. Instead, MySQL Server supports the INSERT INTO ... SELECT standard SQL syntax, which is basically the same thing. According to [Mysql Ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) @isom

Answer (score 1):

You must set Insert Section first then do the selecting... The query should look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO courses (name, location, gid)
SELECT name, location, 1
FROM   courses
WHERE  cid = 2
```

Comment: Please chek my question in the link because the resean i tried this solution is that i have a trigger

Answer (score 0):

The format to insert int to table using select is

```
INSERT INTO table_name1 (field_1, field_2, field3) 
SELECT field_1, field_2, field_3 from table_name2
```

For Your case give us

```
Insert into  mvt(id_piece, article_id_article, code_mvt, origine_mvt, type_mvt, code_art, des_art, qte_old, qte_mvt, qte_new, link_piece)
SELECT 
    32,
    57,     
    'MVT/15/12/0001',
    'BSR/15/12/001',
    'S',
    'ART_039',
    'AAAA',
    a.qte_art,
    1,
    a.qte_art - 1,
    'uuuu' FROM article a
WHERE a.id_article = 57
```

Comment: Please chek my question in the link because the resean i tried this solution is that i have a trigger